# how to install an IntelliJ plugin without uploading it to IntelliJ

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

I've built my .zip file, and I just want to extract it into my ~/Library/Application Support/Intellij-x folder

That doesn't seem to work, and all jetbrains tells me (in their docs) is that I should upload it to their server. "Then everyone has access to it!" as though thats a good thing while I'm trying to test it outside of the sandbox and "You can get it right away!", not mentioning that it has to go through a 2 day moderation.

At first I thought it was that I had set a idea-version since-build to the wrong version, so I tried setting it to 1, but that didn't work.

Any tips on how to get it to work? Do you expect that just extracting it to that folder should work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem with installing plugins like this.

I just installed [IntelliJad 9](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?action=download&id=8024) by putting the extracted folder in `~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea10`. And it works.

Comment: right. so there must be something wrong with my plugin :( - thanks

Answer (score 2):

Works also for intelij12 on maverick. Just installed a php plugin via downloading jar and moving it to:

cp idea-php-alpha-7.jar ~/Library/Application\ Support/IdeaIC12/

You can also go to Settings->plugins->Install plugin from disk